# Image not appearing from embedded URL from Discord.js Bot

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, embed, discord, discord.js

The problem that I am having right now is that the image is not showing up from the URL that I have embedded. Now usually for Discord, when you send an image link it appears like this:
[What usually happens when you send an image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnkgT.png)

Now, I tried to embed the image links. This embedded the image URL fine, however, now the image did not pop out below the image URL but the embed works: [The embedded image URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z7Ur.png)

Here is my current code:

```
} else if(message.content == '/memes' || message.content =='/meme') {
    message.channel.sendMessage({embed: {
        color: 3447003,
        description: memes[Math.floor(Math.random()*75)]
      }});
      //message.reply(memes[Math.floor(Math.random()*75)])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your image URL is coming from `memes[Math.floor(Math.random()*75)]`, is that correct?

You need to also set the URL on the `image` attribute of the embed. Like this:

```
const imageURL = memes[Math.floor(Math.random()*75)];

message.channel.sendMessage({embed: {
    color: 3447003,
    description: imageURL,
    image: {url: imageURL}
}});
```

Also, are you using the standard Discord.js library? If so, I'd recommend not using `.sendMessage` anymore because it is being deprecated. Otherwise, please note which library you're using.